# Match all requests except static assets - unless they are `.php`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a PHP application running on an Apache web server I am trying to show a 503 maintenance page:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```

However, static assets (served directly by Apache) should be excluded from this. Of course I could add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```

However, this will also include the PHP entry points and thus the PHP application would still be accessible via `https://example.com/index.php/foobar`.

I can't seem to wrap my brain around how I could achieve this. i.e. I want

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

to *not* match `.php` files.

Comment: When I've wanted to provide a similar capability, I've used an auto-prepend PHP script returning a redirect to a static maintenance.html to fence the code.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd rather not invoke PHP at all - especially for instances where something in the PHP configuration is getting updated for example.

Comment: You could try `RewriteCond "REQUEST_FILENAME" "\.php$"` but I've no idea if that will work. (You said you want to NOT match php files, but surely you want any php files to be matched and replaced by manitenance.html)

Comment: You can simply combine two `RewriteCond` by a logical `[AND]` or `[OR].`

Comment: @arkascha yes, but not in one go. I think saima ali's answer is the correct one.